# How to rotate/translate a part of body without afecting the rest of it?

Tags: modifiers

Hello Blender wizards,

I've been following a really old tutorial (2009): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUifORl-faI and I've come to a problem.

When I try to rotate **just** the extrusion, the rest of the body rotates as well (7:36 to 7:41).
A similar problem occurs when I try to translate **just a single vertex**, and all other vertices move together (9:05 to 9:10).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have activated the *Proportional Editing* option on the bottom horizontal menu bar. It allows you to influence the closest vertices/edges/faces.

[image]